# GCS API: User doesn't exist

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

That's my first attempt to upload file to google cloud storage and work with google cloud api in general.
I was following this example:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/gspythonlibrary#credentials

and went to the point Creating buckets
Everything works well and running`gsutil mb gs://random_bucket_name2435234234` in terminal create a new bucket.

However when i run this code in python:
    import boto
    import gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin
    import os
    import shutil
    import StringIO
    import tempfile
    import time

```
GOOGLE_STORAGE = 'gs'
LOCAL_FILE = 'file'

now = time.time()
CATS_BUCKET = 'cats-%d' % now
DOGS_BUCKET = 'dogs-%d' % now

project_id = 'ga-export-XXXX'

for name in (CATS_BUCKET, DOGS_BUCKET):
  uri = boto.storage_uri(name, GOOGLE_STORAGE)
  try:
    header_values = {"x-goog-project-id": project_id}
    uri.create_bucket(headers=header_values)

    print 'Successfully created bucket "%s"' % name
  except boto.exception.StorageCreateError, e:
    print 'Failed to create bucket:', e
```

...i get error: 'The User Id you provided does not exist in our records.'
Perhaps it is easy question but being new to all this im struggling to find out where i missed that userid. 
Would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with `gsutill`. It must be standalone version of it and not one from sdk